# Make vite build output the compressed files only

Tags: vite, brotli

So, i am compressing my build with brotli before rsyncing it to my server. The thing is vite gives me both .br files and normal ones. Is this because some filetypes cannot be used if copressed with the algorithm on in case a browser does not support them?

If not, how could i make it so only the compressed versions are outputed?

It's not really an issue it just seems like a waste of space if i am only serving compressed versions to the client